# INSERT MySQL en aplicacion Java Web JSF

Tags: java, mysql, jsf

Estoy creando un CRUD para una aplicacion Java Web pero no logro saber si tengo conexion a la base de datos lo hago de la siguiente manera:

```
public class cConexion {
    private static String servidor = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/pizzeriaufg?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNul";//Agregue  la variable serverTimezone porque daba error en mi pc
    private static String user = "root";
    private static String pass = "";
    private static String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    private static Connection conexion;

    public cConexion() {
        try{
            Class.forName(this.driver);
            this.conexion = DriverManager.getConnection(this.servidor,this.user,this.pass);
            System.out.println("Conexión iniciada con éxito");
        } catch(ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e){
            System.out.println("ERROR CONECTANDO A LA BASE DE DATOS");
        }
    }

    public Connection getConexion(){
        return this.conexion;
    }
}
```

Mi INSERT lo estoy realizando asi:

```
public void insertarDB(){
    cConexion conexionn = new cConexion();
    Connection con = conexionn.getConexion();
    Statement st;
    String sql="insert into pizzeriaufg(id_menu,nombrearticulo,imagen,precio)" + "values('" + getIdmenu() + "','" + getNombrearticulo() + "', '" + getImagen() + "', '" + getPrecio() +"')";
    try{
    st=con.createStatement();
    st.executeUpdate(sql);
    con.close();
    }catch(SQLException e){
    }
```

Sin embargo no logro realizarlo con exito, hay algo que deba cambiar?

Comment: Para empezar, no ignorar las posibles excepciones que te puedan salir, como muy mínimo loguear/imprimir por pantalla la excepción que puedas capturar en el catch.

Comment: Además busca otro código de ejemplo porque el código que tienes está muy anticuado (*Class.forName* no es necesario desde hace mucho), inseguro (concatenar los valores de los parámetros en el SQL trae el riesgo de SQL Injection) y probablemente inadecuado (si estás usando un servidor J2EE como GlassFish o wildfly).

Answer (score 0):

recuerde que para hacer una conexion a una base de datos, tiene que importar una libreria, o eso me toca a mi en netbeans, en su caso es el mysql connector JDBC o algo asi

Comment: Considera que sería de mucha ayuda le indicaras como hacer dicha importación

Comment: Deberias mejorar la respuesta para que pueda entenderte. Es mas un comentario que una respuesta.